# how to sync listview with database in android realtime?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm working on App that have a listview and I should show up a list of data that stored locally in sqlite db, but my db is refreshing in background and i want to sync those changes in my list view immediately.
thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When your database update finished you can send a `broadcast` and in it's receiver you can update the adapter data source and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` in your list adapter to refresh the list.

Comment: Hi and thnx. Would you explain how to do that?

Comment: @user1290224 : the implementation is too broad to answer , here in stackoverflow is huge number of examples which you can search. take your problems apart in small pieces and search for it, Good luck.

Comment: Thnx for answering, but I know that and I need more than this help!

Comment: what if i want to do reverse of this, i want to update data on notifyDataChange of db

Answer (score 0):

You can use a notification whenever your database entries change, it must be known to you when the entries are changing, just raise a notification at the same time and add an observer for the same in the activity in which your listview is present.

And whenever your update function receives a notification update your listview (reload).

Create an observable class, example for this is below:

```
public class TestObserver extends Observable 
{
    private static TestObserver instance;

    public static TestObserver getSharedInstance()
    {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new TestObserver();

        return instance;
    }

    public void raiseNotification(Object data)
    {
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(data);
    }
}


Add this observer in your activity when it is created.Make sure the activity is implementing the Observer interface.

    private void addObserver()
    {
     TestObserver.getSharedInstance.addObserver(this);
    }
```

Also you need to remove the observer when your activity destroys.

```
private void removeObserver()
{
 TestObserver.getSharedInstance.deleteObserver(this);
}
```

You will need to implement a method called update(Observable instance, Object data). That is called whenever a notifications is observed.

From the function where database changes can be determined, raise a notification as

TestObserver.getSharedInstance.raiseNotification(yourObject);//may be a bool specifying whether database changed or not.

Comment: Thnx for answering, pls show me how to do that? I think I should using cursor on my database or something like that. But your solution seems good to me, please explain it to me. thnx.

Comment: Thnx for answering, but this cant help me! I need to know how to write an algorithm to refresh list view without any lags!